# How to include token or variable for Invoice number under the message templates for Memberships - Receipt (on-line)

Tags: wordpress, message-templates, invoice

I need to send Invoice number in the message templates for Membership Receipt Online, but I don't see any token or variables associated for Invoice Number which I can use to place it

is there any way we can place the invoice number in the message templates ?

Comment: The solution proposed seems very good: {crmAPI var='invoiceReference' entity='Contribution' action='getvalue' return="invoice_id" id=$contributionID}
You can print it with {$invoiceReference} But I obtain an array, in which way I could extract the invoice_number?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10341)

Answer (score 3):

The tokens you can use in a message template are a bit random, just what the developer added to the template. In this case, the contribution id can be found with `{$contributionID}`. However, that is not the same as the `invoice_number`. I could not find a token for the invoice number. But the templates are generated by smarty, and in smarty you can use the CiviCRM api. So the following line gets the invoice number:

```
{crmAPI var='invoiceReference' 
        entity='Contribution' 
        action='getvalue' 
        return="invoice_id" 
        id=$contributionID}
```

You can print it with `{$invoiceReference}`

Answer (score 2):

I think this answer is outdated, I can see that the {$invoiceReference} variable is available in the message template - Contributions - Receipt (on-line).

Use the Smarty function in the template to see all the available Smarty variables and their values: **{debug output=html}**